# IBM Bluemix IoT Realtime Insights

Tags: ibm-cloud, real-time, scalability, iot, rule-engine

I have recently started working on IBM Bluemix IoT Platform. I learned that IoT Real-Time Insights delivers a highly scalable, parallel processing rules engine which is designed from the ground up for IoT data. I was wondering how this scaling happens for the large volume of event data. Can somebody explain me the architecture/scalability of IoT platform? Can we configure rule engine (parallel processing) on how may parallel process can be run?

Thanks,
Suhas

Answer (score 2):

As you stated, the analytics engine in the Watson IoT Platform (WIoTP) is designed to be highly salable.  There are two aspects of the scalability; 1) The IoT Connect ability to ingest device messages at high volumes and 2) the analytic engine ability to consume those messages and apply analytics against them.  I will specifically focus on the 2nd aspect.  The analytics engine on Cloud is built on Spark.  Based on the analytics defined by the user, we can scale analytics engine to optimize by device type and number of analytics defined.  We can also scale the Spark jobs based on the above characteristics.  The WIoTP user doesn't need to handle the scalability aspect, that is done as part of the service provided.

Just so you are aware, the IoT Real-Time Insights component has moved into the base WIoTP offering, it is no longer a standalone service.

Comment: Are you trying to say that Realtime Insights has UI to create rules and Storm is a backend to execute those rules? If Storm is used, then where can we configure the throughput parameters - no. of parallel runs/no. of bolts and spouts.